# DevC++ Error Log

Tags: dev-c++

I am teaching C programming for entry-level undergraduate students. I am using Dev-C++ (5.11) for their programming laboratory. I am interested in collecting all the compilation errors students make to analyze where things are going wrong. Is there any facility in Dev-C++ to collect (automatically) all student compilation errors for later analysis. Thank you.

Comment: This question is not really an SO question. It belongs on [cseducators.se].  (Also, it sounds like that's a site that might be useful for you. :)

Comment: Thank you Ben. I would look into computer science educators.